# Compile typescript with corresponding dependencies to upload to AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, aws-lambda

I want to create a service with typescript and upload it to AWS Lambda. When I have it and I run `npm run compile` it creates the corresponding javascript files, but when I zip them and upload them to AWS it does not recognize the configured dependencies that are in package.json, and are imported inside the code. What is the best way to do this in an optimal way? Of course I want to compile the modules that are marked as dependencies, and not the devDependencies.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.673.0",
    "tslog": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "name": "project-name",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.53",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.8.1",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

This is the handler:

```
import {Callback, Context} from "aws-lambda";
import {Logger} from "tslog";

export class Handler{

    public handleRequest(event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback){
        const log: Logger = new Logger()
        log.debug(event)
    }
}
```

And when I run this code in an AWS Lambda it throws:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'tslog'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/build/src/Handler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"
```

Comment: "AWS [...] does not recognize the configured dependencies that are in package.json" - AWS/Lambda does not know or care about your package.json at all. It's up to you to supply a fully working artifact with all dependencies already included. The only one you can leave out is the aws sdk which is always available in lambda the node.js image.

Comment: Yes, I found out that, but what I want to do is to generate the .zip with the corresponding modules, and that must be done with npm commands before generating the zip to upload. The problem is that if I copy the entire node_modules folder the devDependencies will be copied, and it makes the zip much larger.

Comment: Use `npm install --prod` (I think that's it) to install the dependencies only, without devDependencies.

Comment: Doing that installed the dependencies correctly and is much lighter now, but I still have the doubt if this is the correct approach. For now I will go on with this, but if there is any better way to do it I'm open to suggestions! Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to introduce the tslog dependency as lambda layer. 

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-lambda-layers